# Sufficient conditions for closed infinite pasting lemma

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, metric-spaces, continuity

It's well known that the pasting lemma for infinitely many closed sets is false. It's reasonably easy to cook up examples such that for $X = \bigcup X_i$ with $X_i$ closed in $X$ such that $\left. f\right|_{X_i}$ is continuous for all $i$ but $f$ is not continuous.

In Munkres book he places an additional condition in order to formulate an infinite pasting lemma for closed sets, that the collection $\{X_i\}$ be locally finite. What are other "nice" sufficient conditions that force the infinite closed pasting lemma to be true, or is this in some way "minimal"? To restrict the problem a little more we can let $X$ be a metric space since that's the context I'm working in.

Comment: If I may tag along...  I am interested in when this infinite pasting lemma might work for an increasing sequence of closed intervals in a compact linearly ordered space.  I suppose you need them to "sup up" nicely. When I say "sequence" I mean of length an infinite regular cardinal (not necessarily $\omega$).

Comment: That's a bit more general than I'm working for, but I'm hoping for some nice general conditions so those might apply too.

Comment: $f^\leftarrow(A)=\bigcup _if_i ^\leftarrow (A)$. The preimages $f_i^\leftarrow(A)$ preserve closedness of $A$ in $X_i$ and I can't think of a weaker condition than local finiteness that ensures a union of closed sets remains closed.